# Finding the Distribution of N and a Probability Value

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

> Let $X_1,X_2,...X_{10}$ be independent and identically distributed continuous random variables with distribution function $F$ and mean $\mu = E[X_i]$. Let $X_{(1)} < \cdots < X_{(10)}$ be the values arranged in increasing order. That is, for $i = 1, \ldots, 10$, $X_{(i)}$ is the $i$th smallest value of $X_1,X_2,\ldots,X_{10}$.

The first part of the question was pretty easy:

> Find $E\left[\sum\limits_{i=1}^{10} X_{(i)}\right]$.

This is just finding the expected value of a constant.

However, I am struggling with these two parts of the question:

> Let $N = \max\{i : X_{(i)} < x\}$. What is the distribution of $N$?

> If $m$ is the median of the distribution, that is, $F(m) = .5$, find $P(X_{(2)} < m < X_{(8)})$.

I'm honestly not sure where to start on either of these last two parts. Any hints or suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: a will give a hint but it might be wrong, so double check: usually questions involving $\max$ are solved by some trick like this: write the joint cdf $P(X_{(1)} < x, X_{(2)} < x, ... , X_{(n)} < x)$ and realise that this is equivalent to the  joint cdf $P(\max_i\{i : X_{(i)} \} < x)$ since $,$ is actually logical $AND$ i.e. if a bunch of variables are all smaller than $x$ then their maximum is smaller than $x$. You can then work on $P(X_{(1)} .... X_{(n)})$ and try to use independence somehow: $X_{(1)}, .. X_{(n)}$ are not independent since they are sorted, but probably there's some other tric

Comment: Please ignore my comment: I misunderstood we are looking for the argmax of the $X(i)$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $N=j$ then exact $j$ out of $10$ of the observations are less than $x$ and exactly $10-j$ of the observations are at least $x$. Hence $$N\sim \text{Binomial}\Big(10,F(x)\Big)$$ For the second part, notice how $E_i:=\{X_{(i)}<m<X_{(i+1)}\}$ occurs iff exactly $i$ observations are less than $m$ and exactly $10-i$ observations are larger than $m$, where $1\leq i \leq 9$ is a fixed positive integer. Therefore $\mathbb{P}(E_i)={10 \choose i}(1/2)^{10}$ and so $$\mathbb{P}\Big(X_{(2)}<m<X_{(8)}\Big)=\mathbb{P}(E_2)+\dots +\mathbb{P}(E_7)=(1/2)^{10}\sum_{i=2}^7{10 \choose i}$$